Span/Trace-ID not set
I setup a OTEL but the spanId/traceId is not injected into the "header". The Attributes and span is send to the OTEL-Collector/JaegerUI, that is fine. Only the spanId/traceId are not set, that each service is connected together:
package com.example.starter;


import io.opentelemetry.api.trace.Span;
import io.opentelemetry.api.trace.StatusCode;
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Handler;
import io.vertx.core.Promise;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerOptions;
import io.vertx.core.tracing.TracingPolicy;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;
import io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext;

public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  OpenTelemetryTracer otel = OpenTelemetryTracer.getTracer();

  final Handler<RoutingContext> loggingHandler = routingContext -> {
              Span span = otel.receiveRequest(routingContext);
              routingContext.addEndHandler(v -> {
                  span.setStatus(StatusCode.OK,"Hurray");
                  span.end();
                });
              routingContext.put("span", span);
              routingContext.next();
            };

  @Override
  public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) throws Exception {

      Router router = Router.router(vertx);

      router.get("/test/test")
            .handler(loggingHandler)
            .handler( req -> {
          req.response()
            .putHeader("content-type", "text/plain");
          req.response().end("Hello from Vert.x!\n");
      });
      router.get("/test/test1/:name")          
              .handler(loggingHandler)
              .handler( req -> {
          req.response()
            .putHeader("content-type", "text/plain");
          req.response().end("Hello from Vert.x!\n");
      });
      vertx.createHttpServer(new HttpServerOptions().setTracingPolicy(TracingPolicy.ALWAYS)).
      requestHandler(router).listen(10000, http -> {
          if (http.succeeded()) {
              startPromise.complete();
              System.out.println("HTTP server started on port 10000");
          } else {
              startPromise.fail(http.cause());
          }
      });
  }
}

package com.example.starter;

import java.util.HashMap;
import io.opentelemetry.api.common.Attributes;
import io.opentelemetry.api.common.AttributesBuilder;
import io.opentelemetry.api.trace.Span;
import io.opentelemetry.api.trace.SpanBuilder;
import io.opentelemetry.api.trace.Tracer;
import io.opentelemetry.api.trace.propagation.W3CTraceContextPropagator;
import io.opentelemetry.context.propagation.ContextPropagators;
import io.opentelemetry.context.propagation.TextMapGetter;
import io.opentelemetry.context.propagation.TextMapSetter;
import io.opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.trace.OtlpGrpcSpanExporter;
import io.opentelemetry.context.Context;
import io.opentelemetry.sdk.OpenTelemetrySdk;
import io.opentelemetry.sdk.resources.Resource;
import io.opentelemetry.sdk.trace.SdkTracerProvider;
import io.opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export.BatchSpanProcessor;
import io.vertx.core.MultiMap;
import io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext;

public class OpenTelemetryTracer {
 
    final static OpenTelemetryTracer otel = new OpenTelemetryTracer();
    private OpenTelemetrySdk openTelemetrySdk;
    private Tracer otelTracer;

    private static final TextMapGetter<MultiMap>               getter = new HeadersPropagatorGetter();
    private static final TextMapSetter<HashMap<String,String>> setter = new HeadersPropagatorSetter();

    public static OpenTelemetryTracer getTracer() {
        return OpenTelemetryTracer.otel;
    }

    OpenTelemetryTracer() {
        
        Resource resource = Resource.getDefault()
                            .merge(Resource.builder()
                                            .put("service.name", "Test")
                                            .put("service.version", "1.0.0").build());
 
        OtlpGrpcSpanExporter spanExporter = OtlpGrpcSpanExporter.builder()
                                            .setEndpoint("http://localhost:4317")
                                            .build();

        SdkTracerProvider sdkTracerProvider = SdkTracerProvider.builder()
                                            .addSpanProcessor(BatchSpanProcessor.builder(spanExporter).build())
                                            .setResource(resource)
                                            .build();

        openTelemetrySdk = OpenTelemetrySdk.builder()
                        .setTracerProvider(sdkTracerProvider)
                        .setPropagators(ContextPropagators.create(W3CTraceContextPropagator.getInstance()))
                        .buildAndRegisterGlobal();
        otelTracer  = openTelemetrySdk.getTracer("Test");
    }

    public Span receiveRequest ( final RoutingContext request) {

        Context otelCtx = Context.current();
        ContextPropagators propagators = openTelemetrySdk.getPropagators();

        otelCtx = propagators.getTextMapPropagator().extract(otelCtx, request.request().headers(), getter);

        AttributesBuilder builder = Attributes.builder();
        builder.put("http.request.method",    request.request().method().name());
        builder.put("url.path",               request.request().path());
        builder.put("http.scheme",            request.request().scheme());
        builder.put("http.route",             request.currentRoute().getName());

        SpanBuilder spanBuilder = otelTracer
                                    .spanBuilder(request.currentRoute().getName())
                                    .setParent(otelCtx)
                                    .setSpanKind(io.opentelemetry.api.trace.SpanKind.SERVER)
                                    .setAllAttributes(builder.build());
        Span span = spanBuilder.startSpan();
        
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();

        propagators.getTextMapPropagator().inject(otelCtx, map, setter);
        System.out.println("Span-Id: " + span.getSpanContext().getSpanId());
        System.out.println("Trace-Id: " + span.getSpanContext().getTraceId());
        System.out.println("Inject: " + map.toString());
        
        return span;
    }

}

Output
Span-Id: 4103b1f8b0b16a9f
Trace-Id: e7579ad158b1567b8a422d5bbf591879
Inject: {}

I see within the debugger, that the otelCtx is empty. What did I missed, that the spanId and traceId is propagated into the HashMap?

With the line otelCtx = span.StoreContext(otelCtx), it worked. Since I didn’t find such hints, I don’t know if this the correct way.
